# Code can't be executed if is in a class function

Tags: php, class

I coded this snippet, and it works well when I use it alone without putting it in a class function, but when I put in a function in my class that had multi functions, the update and delete statements didn't work, although the insert function works well. I don't know why the update and delete don't work.

I checked the code for 4 hours, but I don't know what's the problem.

Is this a problem related to using the way to update multiple columns in a table?

```
public function admin_ads_manage(){

/*###############site_links#################*/
$sel_links="SELECT * FROM site_links ORDER BY id DESC";
$query_sel_links=mysql_query($sel_links);

// Count table rows
$count_links=mysql_num_rows($query_sel_links);

//add data

$site_name=$_POST['addname'];
$site_link=$_POST['addlink'];

if($_POST['addsubmit']){
$add_site_links="INSERT INTO site_links(site_name,site_link) VALUES ('$site_name','$site_link')";
$query_add_site_links=mysql_query($add_site_links);
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"";
}

/*###############site_links#################*/
?>  

<div id="adsform">
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">

<h1>ادارة أضف لنك موقعك</h1>

<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr><td>اسم الموقع:<input type="text" name="addname" ></td><td>الرابط:<input type="text" name="addlink"><td><input type="submit" name="addsubmit" value="اضف الرابط" ></td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">


<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>اسم الموقع</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>رابط الموقع</strong></td>

</tr>
<?php
while($fetch_site_links=mysql_fetch_array($query_sel_links)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $fetch_site_links['id']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><? $id[]=$fetch_site_links['id']; ?><? echo $fetch_site_links['id']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><input name="sitename[]" type="text" id="sitename" value="<? echo $fetch_site_links['site_name']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="sitelink[]" type="text" id="sitelink" value="<? echo $fetch_site_links['site_link']; ?>"></td>

</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="تعديل"></td>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="حذف"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>



</table>


<h1>اعلان اليوم</h1>    
<h5 dir="rtl">لاضافة بنر لموضع اعلان اليوم ,كل ما عليك هو استبدال الصورة الموجودة فى مجلدimages بحيث تكون بنفس المقاسات والتى تساوى100 x 300</h5>



<p>adsense 728x90:الاعلان العرضى</p>
<p><textarea cols="50" rows="15" name="ads728"><?php echo $file728; ?></textarea></p>

<p>adsense 600x160:الاعلان المربع</p>
<p><textarea cols="50" rows="15" name="ads600"><?php echo $file600; ?></textarea></p>


<p>adsense 300x250:الاعلان الطولى</p>
<p><textarea cols="50" rows="15" name="ads300"><?php echo $file300 ?></textarea></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="حفظ" /></p>

</form> 

<?php
// Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this
if($Submit){
for($i=0;$i<$count_links;$i++){
$upd_site_links="UPDATE site_links SET site_name='$sitename[$i]', site_link='$sitelink[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
$query_upd_site_links=mysql_query($upd_site_links);
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\">";
}
}

if($delete){
for($i=0;$i<$count_links;$i++){
$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$del_links = "DELETE FROM site_links WHERE id='$del_id'";
$query_del_links= mysql_query($del_links);

}}

if($query_del_links){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" >";
}

if($query_upd_site_links){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" >";
}



}
```

Comment: Do you get error messages if you check `mysql_error()` when the queries failed?  Or any other error messages?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections, check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: drew,the code works well when i use it alone without putting it in a class

Comment: peter,iknew this, am just build the core,then i'll secure all queries

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the code in the class function actually has access to all the variables you're using. I imagine that one of them isn't in scope.

`$checkbox`, `$sitename`, `$sitelink`, `$id` and `$count_links` may be the most likely culprits.

EDIT: Is all that one single function? You should break that up into smaller functions, each of which does one single thing.

Comment: yes,all in one single function,and i am sure the code has access to all vars,still dk what's the problem,

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems.

- Where is the `mysqli_connect()` (or equivalent)? Your function seems to be relying on whatever connection handle the library last used. This is not good coding.
- Your `UPDATE` loop sends a HTTP refresh for each row.
- In fact, your action logic is littered through your display logic. This is also bad coding.
- But the biggest thing is that you seem to be relying on [`register_globals`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) and you aren't even aware of it. [You should turn this off](http://au.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Your action code needs to retrieve all the variables it is looking for out of `$_POST` or `$_GET` (or `$_REQUEST` if it doesn't matter which). And each action (of which you have a couple) should only do what its asked to do once all the variables it needs are accounted for. It is really bad coding to assume that all field variables are automatically global variables.